# PHP/MySQL unidentified index error

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP assignment which requires me to create a search form that searches a databases with the criteria input by the user. In the MySQL database I have a firstName and lastName columns. To make it easier for the user I wanted to the concatenate the to and input it in a listbox so the user could click the person name however I am now getting an undefined index error. I have researched for a solution but haven't been able to find one.

I am connecting to the server and the database elsewhere in the file. I have shown only the code relevant to the problem below.

Form code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset style="background-color:#CCC">
    <p> person: <?php fullname(); ?><br>
    </fieldset>
</form>

function fullname()
{
    $query = 'SELECT CONCAT (firstName,\' \',lastName) FROM athlete ORDER BY lastName';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo("<select name=\"fullnameListbox\">");
    echo("<option value=\"empty\"></option>"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        foreach($row as $index=>$value)
        {
            echo("<option value=\"$value\"> $value </option>"); 
        }
    }
    echo("</select>");
}
```

The processing form:

```
echo($_POST['fullnameListbox']);
```

I repeat the error I am getting an unidentified index error. Any help is appreciated.

I inlcluded print_r($_POST) as suggested below and i get the following:

```
( [lastNameListbox] => empty [lastNameText] => [search] => Submit )
```

I take it that lastNameListBox is empty even though I have clicked a name in the listbox so theoretically it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Try: `<select name='fullnameListbox'>`, in order to debug the posted data, use `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Where do you actually *make* your `mysql` connection?

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but I wonder why you have `foreach($row as $index=>$value)` when the query always returns just one column. Use `SELECT CONCAT (firstName,\' \',lastName) as fullName` and then `$row['fullName']`.

Answer (score 1):

An unidentified index **notice** is a PHP **notice** relating to trying to access array indexes that were not initialized yet.

```
$_GET['some_key_name']++; // will result in such a notice
                          // if the array key was never initialised

if(isset($_GET['some_key_name'])) // will not result in such a notice
    $_GET['some_key_name']++;     // will not result in such a notice
else
    $_GET['some_key_name'] = 1;   // will not result in such a notice
```

Comment: This is the only reason for such a notice, that must mean you haven't done this where you should have. Show us that part of the code.

Comment: i've put the following code in the processing file '<?php

if(isset($_GET['fullnameListbox'])) // will not result in such a notice
    $_GET['fullnameListbox']++;     // will not result in such a notice
else
    $_GET['fullnameListbox'] = 1;

print_r($_POST);

echo($_POST['fullnameListbox']);'

Comment: is there a better way I could concatenate two databases columns and put each row into the listbox so the user can select a person name to return a result?

Comment: `$_GET =/= $_POST`if the variable came in by POST $_GET won't contain it and vice-versa. You're checking if $x exists and then using $y. Of course it'll still trigger the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Hi first you have to connect database then only you can  execute the query as well.

```
<?php
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
   if (!$con)
   {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
 // some code
 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

Try this..

Comment: this is elsewhere in the file. I have only shown the code relavant to the problem. I will include this in the question.